# sudoers not working for tar command

Tags: ubuntu, backup, tar, sudo

I want to disable the requirement of `sudo` or running as `root` for a bash script that does backups with `tar`.

I added this line to my sudoers file

```
username ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/tar
```

However after I added that it still shows permissions denied when I run this backup command

```
/bin/tar -cvpzf /root/sysBackup/backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/sys --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/media --exclude=/dev /
```

These are the errors

```
/bin/tar: Removing leading `/' from member names                                                                                                          
tar (child): /root/sysBackup/backup.tar.gz: Cannot open: Permission denied                                                                                
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You still need to run it as root, are you typing sudo first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You still need to start your tar command via sudo inside your bash script:

```
sudo /bin/tar -cvpzf /root/sysBackup/backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/sys --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/media --exclude=/dev /
```